# Cleanup script instead of searching in the provided path always hitting at either system root or the root folder it runs from

Tags: linux, bash, shell

### Summary

We have few thousands folder on a server with deep directory structure, there is a list of folders in the directory structure we've to iterate through, then all those folders contain a similar folder "A" in each one of them.

1 - loop through a list of specific folder names and search them at a location on disk. (list.txt)

2 - locate folder "A" in each of the folder located above. (/folder/location/A)

3 - in folder "A" delete everything except *.zip files.

### Script

```
#!/bin/bash

# list containing all folder names
list=$(</opt/script/test.txt)


# loop
for i in $list

do
        

        # folders from list location. (Errors out here, starts hitting '.' or /root)
        folder=$(find /path/to/listfolders/ -type d -name $i)

        # folder A location
        A=$(find $folder -type d -name A)
        
        # folder A - Before deletion
        file_count_1=$(find $A -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
        folder_count_1=$(find $A -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -type d | wc -l)
        size_1=$(du -sh $A)
        echo "folders: $folder_count_1 || files: $file_count_1 || Size is: $size_1"
```

---

### Issue

This script ran fine on few hundred folders then something broke. Now whenever this script is run it either starts deleting from system /root folder or start deleting from the folder it is saved in. It is not locating the folder path that is give.

*This runs*
find i in $list; do echo $i; done

*This doesn't*
find i in $list; do find /path/to/a/location/ -type d -name $i; done

it always hits at '/root' or '.' but not at '/path/to/location/'

Some functionality seems to have broken, not sure which one.

### Tried

I tried to run find on individual folders & files with different locations just from bash (no script)
find i in $Difflist; do find /path/to/another/location/ -type d -name $i; done

but find is just not working with reference of items ($i) in a loop.

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU/BSD `find` and GNU `grep`.

Since there is no actual directory structures provided by the OP, the first thing to do is check if there is a match by doing

```
find /path/to/listfolders -type d | grep -Fx -f /opt/script/test.txt
```

---

`grep` has more option/flags, change `-x` to `-w` if needed

---

```
-w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words

-x, --line-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole lines

-f, --file=FILE           obtain PATTERN from FILE

-F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings
```

- See `man grep` or `grep --help` if present.

---

If there is an output from `grep` then it can be use in the script, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

path=/path/to/listfolders
list=/opt/script/test.txt

while IFS= read -rd '' directory; do
  echo rm "$directory/"!(*.zip) || exit
done < <(
  find "$path" -type d -print0 | grep -Fzx -f "$list"
)
```

---

- See [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)
- See [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob)
- See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- Again change `-x` to `-w` from `grep` if needed.
- `rm` has a lot of options/flag but most probably you need the `-r` and `-f`

  - -f, --force           ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
  - -r, -R, --recursive   remove directories and their contents recursively
- grep option: `-z, --null-data a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline`
- See [Howto handle files with spaces and newlines](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)
- See the [shopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) section of the bash manual.
- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied by the output.
- Might need to pipe the output of `grep` to (GNU) `sort -zu`